# Replace all text in XML with python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a word document that was saved as an xml. I am trying to replace words in the file from a dictionary. My previous attempt did not involve any XML parsing and worked pretty well.

```
    import pickle 
    mine=open('dictionary.txt')
    D=pickle.load(mine)
    mine.close()
    mine = open('text.xml')
    t = mine.read()
    Ks = D.keys()
    for key in Ks:
            t=t.replace(key,D1[key])
```

Unforunately, due to the nature of Microsoft Word some replacements do not get made as they are split with XML tags. I want to use ElementTree to parse the XML to solve this problem. I am having some problems with my current implementation.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pickle

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

mine=open('testDict.txt')
D=pickle.load(mine)
mine.close()
Ks=D.keys()

for key in Ks:
    tree.find(key).text = D1[key]

tree.write('test.xml', xml_declaration = True, encoding = "UTF-8", method = "xml", standalone = "yes")
```

This throws an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the XML document, but one of your keys is not being found during `tree.find(key)`.  Perhaps print out the keys to see which one is failing?  This will tell you if you have implemented the behavior incorrectly (for example *nothing* is being found) or if there is actually a key that doesn't exist in your document.

Comment: also, you set the `root` variable, but don't end up using it

Comment: The XML document is really long and would not fit on this page. I could try and create a sample, but my knowledge of XML structure is limited.

Comment: @Bman425 do you actually have a docx file?

Comment: Yes, I have the docx file but I save it as an xml